# MongoDB authentication doesn't work when a docker-volume is defined

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I use the following lines to define a mongodb docker container with docker-compose:

```
mongo:
  image: mongo
  container_name: mongodb
  hostname: ${host}
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${user}
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${password}
  ports:
    - "${port}:27017"
  volumes:
    - ./mongodb/data:/data/db
```

Like this, I get an error (`Authentication failed.`) when I try to connect to mongodb via MongoDB Compass. After two hours of despair I found out that it works when I remove the `volumes` part in the docker-compose file.

What's the problem with the volume and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the problem by my self. I had to delete everything that was already in the volume directory on my host-machine (the content of the `./mongodb/data` folder). I previously used the mongodb container without authentication. I assume it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. My app works well without the volumes part. I solved the issue using `docker compose down --volumes` ([See prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZvN0.png)) and running again the command `docker compose up`.